# display link in light box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, lightbox, lightbox2

in the light box i am trying to retrieve the data from the data caption
it works fine when i give p tag, div tag
but it does not work for a tag with href on it
in the light box i wanted to display links which redirect to some other page

providing my fiddle below

http://jsfiddle.net/ZrpLT/88/

```
<div data-caption="&lt;a href="http://www.w3schools.com/" &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt;View/Edit&lt;/div&gt; &lt;div&gt;Labels&lt;/div&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/thumbnails/inventory.png"></div>
<div data-caption="<div>Paul Scholes</div> <div>Wayne Rooney</div> <div>Sir Alex Ferguson</div>" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/thumbnails/search.png"><div>ko kopkopwkop</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your double quotes around the HREF attribute break the data-caption. Single quotes work:

http://jsfiddle.net/hansvedo/pRvjC/1/

```
<div data-caption="&lt;a href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt;View/Edit&lt;/div&gt; &lt;div&gt;Labels&lt;/div&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/thumbnails/inventory.png"></div>
```